# Printing individual parts of an array in a Java Gui app

Tags: java, arrays, swing, actionlistener

OK, so I created a console app that, among other things, takes an array of numbers and prints them out one by one, line by line. Now, I have to take the class that I created for that console app, and pop it into a separate GUI app we're creating. I have all of the other methods working fine, but for the life of me I cannot get the array method to print out correctly. It just gives me the last number I typed into the text field. I'm hoping someone can give me a nudge to help me figure this part out so I can move along, and get to the whole SpringLayout stuff, (the main part of the new assignment) I am limited in what I can show you here because this is a current assignment, so I will have to stick to this stuff as specifically as I can. And please, don't just post the code as an answer, (because then I can't use it), thanks.
Here's what I had for my original project for the array method:

```
  int [] getArray(int x)
  {
    breakUpNum(x);
    return numAry;
  }
```

From there, inside my new class I have this, in an attempt to get it to print:

```
private class ButtonTest implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        Lab1 tester = new Lab1();

        int[] test4 = tester.getArray(num);

        for(int i = 0; i < test4.length; i ++)
        {
        crossTest.getArrCross.setText("" + test4[i]);
        }              

    }
}
```

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setText` does just that, sets the text you pass to as the current text content, it does not append it.

If you were to use `JTextArea`, you could use it's `append` method...however, for a `JTextField` you need to have a different approach.

Now you could use `getArrCross.setText(getArrCross.getText() + test4[i])`...but to quite frank, that's rather inefficient, as each call to `setText` is going to stage a paint event...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
for(int i = 0; i < test4.length; i ++)
{
    sb.append(test4[i]);
}          
crossTest.getArrCross.setText(sb.toString());
```

Now, if you want to separate each element, you need to add

```
if (sb.length() > 0) {
    sb.append(", ");
}
```

Before `sb.append(test4[i]);`

Comment: Ok, so here's a question, if I'm using SpringLayout and want to be able to set the spacing between each result via the SpringLayout, would this work? This is assuming I want to print all results on a single line, spaced evenly

Comment: How do you want to print them?  In a `JTextField`? `JLabel`? `JTextArea`?  If you're using a `JTextField` do you need to place them in separate text fields?

Comment: Best way I can explain it is to have it look like this: ARRAY  1         2         3, on one line. Ok, that doesnt work in this text filed. Basically, you have one line where the output shows up, and it is spread evenly within the allowed space, so a three digit number would have say 20 pixels of spacing between them, but a six digit number would only have 10 pixels between them each, does that make sense? I don't even know if thats possible. I'm looking up all the stuff available to SpringLayout, but I don't see where that can be done

Comment: You should be able to use a non editable `JTextField` to achomplish this, the reason I suggest it is because `JTextField` has it's own clipping capabilities, where as `JLabel` (or multiple `JLabel`s) won't clip as nicely, or allow you to scroll beyond the visibility range if the text over flows.  This is why I added the `sb.append(", ");` section...

Answer (score 1):

The last bit of `actionPerformed` in the for loop isn't working right. `setText` replaces the current text with its argument, and it doesn't seem like you want to do that. To fix it, replace the line in the for loop with this:

```
crossTest.getArrCross.setText(crossTest.getArrCross.getText() + test4[i]);
```

Comment: I tried getText before, but not like this. It didn't even occur to me that you could do that, thanks!